# How to use REST endpoints to return HTML and JSON in different calls

Tags: html, json, laravel, rest, api

I'm creating a website where I want to perform CRUD operations to a dataset. For the sake of simplicity, assume a table of books. I understand that `example.com/books` should return a list of books, and `example.com/books/24` should return the book with id 24.

Now, imagine that my list of books is very large, and I want to allow the user to browse the book list using a table with pagination, but as the dataset is very large I want to retrieve only the current page using AJAX.

The question is: should `example.com/books` return the HTML containing the table with all pagination controls and other widgets? or should it return the data in JSON format? What would be the right way to perform both calls.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller you could do something like this:

```
function index (Request $request){

 $books = Book::paginate(10);

 if($request->ajax()){
    //ajax request 
   return Response::json(view('books', compact('books'))->render());
  }

  //html request
  return view('books', compact('books'));

}
```

You can pass a `page` parameter to the route to navigate to pages.
Example : `example.com/books?page=2` will fetch the second page of results.

> Suggested Approach

Render the initial request with as html like you would normaly do. Then for the next page, get the second page rendered as an ajax call and append it to the DOM.

`return Response::json(view('books', compact('books'))->render());`

```
$('.pager a').on('click', function (e) {
     var page = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
     e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'page=' + page,
      dataType: 'json',
      success:function(json){
         alert("Success"+json);
      },
      error:function(){
         alert("Error");
     }      
    });
  });
 });
```

Take a look at [Laravel Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination)